# Why real valued harmonic functions are holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, analyticity

Let $f$ be a real valued harmonic function on $C,$ then Claim $g= \frac {\partial f}{\partial x} - i \frac {\partial f}{\partial y} $ as holomorphic and  $h= \frac {\partial f}{\partial x} + i \frac {\partial f}{\partial y} $ as need not be holomorphic.

My Attempt

To prove g as holomorphic, we need to satisfy two conditions

1. C.R Eqns :
   $u_x = \dfrac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial ^2 x} = v_y = -\dfrac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial ^2 y}$ ($\because$ f is homomorphic )
2. $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ exists and continous.

Here existence is guaranteed BUT HOW TO VERIFY THE CONTINUITY OF $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$

Comment: Calculate $\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}$. Use chain rule.

Comment: What makes you think that the partial derivatives are both identically zero?

Comment: BTW, if it is identically zero, then it is holomorphic.

Comment: Actually, it was a Multiple Choice question. The  option identically zero is incorrect.

Comment: I mean derivative becomes zero if its a real valued function of a complex variable.

Comment: [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Riemann_equations)

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is harmonic, $f \in C^2$ by definition, so your function is automatically smooth enough to Cauchy-Riemann's equations (in the "other direction".)

Comment: Ya, existence of $ \dfrac {\partial ^2 f} {\partial ^2 x} $  is guaranteed but what abt continuity ?

Comment: No, $C^2$ means that all second-order partial derivatives exist and are continuous.

Comment: @mrf Sir Harmonic function need not satify Cauchy Reimann equation , So how can we talk about holomorphicity ?